# Using find typescript method to return a value in angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am implementing an `Angular 4` *application* that will read a number based on the query that returns it.

I am unable to understand *how the find method will be used to return the result*.

The Options is of the type

```
export interface Option  {
   id: number;
   name: string;
   value: number;
}
```

I need to return value based on the name. How do I return the value. The code i am trying to write is as follows

```
get numberOfBins(): number {
   return numBins = this.options.find(x => x.name === ;
}
```

Comment: `find` is not Typescript specific, that's a Javascript Array function.

Comment: can you confirm `this.options` is an *Array* of Option ?

Answer (score 2):

You can just do the below with find

```
get numberOfBins(): number {
   let binsNum = this.options.find(x => x.name === 'name');        
   return binsNum;
}
```

**EDIT**
Since i was having filter method in mind, you can do the following with filter method

```
get numberOfBins(): number {
    let numBins = this.options.filter(x => x.name === 'name');
    if(numBins && numBins.length > 0){
      return numBins[0].value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you check for `numBins.length` and do `numBins[0].value`? `find` method will return the first item, which fits the `x.name === 'name'` expression, the result will not be an array

Comment: Yeah, it makes sense, these methods are close )

Comment: Now you oversimplified that :] The null check should stay in case there is no match, and you need to return `value` of the match (as the return type suggests), not the match itself.